# No relations/tables found using psycopg2 even after committing

Tags: postgresql, psycopg2, psql

I got started with psycopg2 and have basic level understanding of psql too. I did create a table in one of the DB earlier which was successful. However, *when trying to create a table for a new DB , the table is not being created.*
There are no errors, `psycopg2` is correctly installed on my Windows10 and I have used `commit()` to make the db changes persisitent too. I used the pgAdmin4 GUI to check and the DB is created , however there are no tables created.

**IDE - VSCode  ; Postgres v12.2**

**Code for reference**

```
import psycopg2

connection = psycopg2.connect('dbname=todoapp')

cursor = connection.cursor()

# drop existing table
# cursor.execute('DROP TABLE IF EXISTS todo;')

cursor.execute('''
    CREATE TABLE todo(
        id serial PRIMARY KEY,
        description varchar NOT NULL
    );
''')

cursor.execute('INSERT INTO todo(id, description) VALUES (1, buy 2L milk);')

connection.commit()

connection.close()
cursor.close()
```

**NO relations found**
[image: no relations found]

Comment: In psql, did you connect to the todoapp database?

Comment: Yes I am connected to the todoapp DB as can be seen from the prompt too

Comment: @AnantaKRoy could it be that you're forgetting the `'` in your insert statement and your script is rolling back the whole thing? Try `INSERT INTO todo(id, description) VALUES (1, 'buy 2L milk');`

Comment: I tried that too @JimJones after posting this question. That does not solve the issue.

Comment: @AnantaKRoy that's odd. Do you have multiple schemas in your database?

Comment: @JimJones It is the only schema which I am creating.I could make it work now and have no idea why it happens so . Changed the insert to `"INSERT INTO todo(id, description) VALUES (1, 'Buy Milk');"` . The quotes were messing this up. Using double quotes solved the issue.

Comment: @AnantaKRoy so my first impulse seems to be right :D Nice you found the solution :)

Comment: Your code fails with an error.  If the errors are not visible to you, then that is the problem you need to solve.

Comment: If this is solved, please add a solution post in the answer space below.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The single quotes were messing this up. Using double quotes solved the issue.
Changed the insert query to "INSERT INTO todo(id, description) VALUES (1, 'Buy Milk');" .